# Does Markov Chain with infinite state space (i.e. S = {0,1,2,...} have equilibrium distribution?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

This question might be super stupid and dumb, but I still have to ask. I thought equilibrium distribution only exists for finite states Markov chain. But my course book did give me a example with state space $S=\{0,1,2,... \}$. 
[image]

It talked a lot, but somehow appears to claim there is no equilibrium distribution. Because it violates the condition that $\sum_{i\in S}\pi_i=1$

I am completely confused by it. Does equilibrium distribution for Markov Chain with infinite many state space exist, does it always exist or conditionally exist, or never?

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case there is no equilibrium distribution (rather obviously there is a tendency to drift right)

But suppose instead, for example you had $$X_{n+1}= \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
X_{n}-1 & \text{with probability } \frac{X_n}{X_n+2}  \\
X_n & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{X_n+2} \\
X_{n}+1 & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{X_n+2}  \end{array}\right.$$

then there would be a stable distribution on the non-negative integers

In fact this seems to have a stable distribution of $\pi_j = \dfrac{j +2}{3e j!}$

Comment: Hmmm, it appears you need to set $X_n \geq 1$ for your example, and set $P(X_{n+1}=1|X_n = 0)=1$, Otherwise $X_{n+1}$ may fall down to negative integer

Comment: @FBI_OPEN_UP - I think not: I have $P(X_{n+1}=1 \mid X_n=0)=\frac12$ and  $P(X_{n+1}=0 \mid X_n=0)=\frac12$ and  $P(X_{n+1}=-1 \mid X_n=0)=\frac02$

Comment: Could you please show me how you solved it out? And, does this e represent the constant e? e=2.718?

Comment: @FBI_OPEN_UP indeed $e = \sum\limits_0^\infty \frac1{n!} \approx 2.718$. I worked it out finding $\pi_1=\frac3{2\times 1}\pi_0,\pi_2=\frac4{3\times 2}\pi_1,\pi_3=\frac5{4\times 3}\pi_2$ etc. then added them all up to get a sum of $\frac{3e}2  \pi_0$ enabling me to find the general term